# unable to delete dir from PATH

Tags: bash, bashrc

I once had in ~/.bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/projects/bin
```

I deleted this line long ago from ~/.bashrc but still any terminal that I open this path continues to appear ?
How to permanently delete it from $PATH ?

Comment: Look at `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/`

Comment: Running shells don’t pick up updates to .bashrc; restart them or source the file.

Comment: This is the issue I don't understand how this path is so sticky or how to debug his issue  @Jeff Schaller

Comment: Again, running processes do not pick up updates to `.bashrc`. How are you starting the terminals? Does for example the X11 server have the old environment setting still? Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: I click on the File->Open Tab (Shift+Ctrl+N) or File->Open Terminal (Shift+Ctrl+T)  in the terminal window menu. The issue does seem like the old env settings are saved somewhere @thrig

Comment: Are you running in a graphical desktop environment? Perhaps it was started from a bash shell that had exported the old PATH. In that case, you could either restart your whole login session or update .bashrc to explicitly set PATH to the desired directories (without including $PATH on the right-hand side).

Comment: I was connected with NX, when I terminated the session and created a new one the problem was solved. I don't understand why @Jeff Schaller

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that [NX you mentioned in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401218/unable-to-delete-dir-from-path#comment716973_401218) is [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/everybody), and knowing that after you started a new session, the problem went away, and not having any direct experience with NX, it's my belief that the NoMachine software running on the target had inherited a PATH that was exported from the environment it started in. That environment had the "old" PATH. Once you edited your .bashrc to update the PATH, you had to restart the NX session so that it could start a new process and read your updated .bashrc.